How to search for multiple instances of a file with different directories
I'm working on a utility that needs to find specific files in an environment.
I have a filename that I need to determine the location of, however this filename can exist in several different directories.
As an example:
/opt/projectDir/filename
/opt/projectDir/subDir/subsubdir1/filename
/opt/projectDir/subDir/subsubdir2/filename

I can run a find command and get all of these fairly simply with something like
find /opt -iname "*filename*"

However, this would return all three files, for my usecase I only need the two files that are in the subsubdir
The catch is the subsubdir is a unique ID, and I wont know what it is
I was thinking something like
find /opt -iname "/opt/projectDir/*/filename"

But it doesn't return any results, I was also thinking about regex searching for this, but I just can't seem to get the expression correct.
Are there any built in commands that can assist in finding these files

Figured it out, just needed more coffee 
Can be found like this
find /opt -type f -regex ".*projectDir/.*/filename"

